# Excel search for rightmost non-empty cell in a row, and return the content of cell a couple of rows above

Tags: excel, formula

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have an inspection list for several equipments that someone fills up every week. The person searches for the current week and puts an ''x'' under each aspect inspected for the chosen equipement. I want to get, for each equipment, the last week that the person entered an ''x''.

If you look on the linked image, column 1 is the equipment list, and column marked as 2 is where I want the last date to appear.

[image]

I already tried doing an embeded IF but I would have to do 52 IF's in one formula which is impossible.I've been trying for days for a solution but can't find something to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the dates in merged cells? That will affect your answer. Also, none of my business, but I bet at least some of your users would appreciate a less-blinding color scheme :-)

Comment: Yes, the dates are in merged cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX($3:$3,1,MATCH("zzz",$E5:$ABD5,1)-MOD(MATCH("zzz",$E5:$ABD5,1),14)+COLUMN($E$3))
```

The magic is in `INDEX()` mixed with `MATCH()` and the rest is to make it work in you specific scenario.

According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), `MATCH()`

> searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range

`MATCH`

- `"zzz"` - The value to be searched for
- `$E5:$ABD5` - The range on each row that will be searched for x's
- `1` - Means that it will find the last value in the range that is "less than" the "zzz".

`MOD()` Determines how far through each week the x is

`MOD`

- `MATCH("zzz",$E5:$ABD5,1)` - The position of the last x in that row
- `14` - This is the number of inspections you have in the list

`COLUMN($E$3)` is the column of the cell your first date is in

According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD) `INDEX()`

> returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range

`INDEX`

- `$3:$3` - The range (in this case the row) that the dates for each week are on
- `1` - The row of the range you are interested in
- `MATCH() - MOD() + COLUMN()` finds the first column in the week of the last x

Comment: @Jacquez
Okay, I tried your formula. 

Match: I told to search for ''x'' in the range E5:R5. (Equipment No. A-001, under week 04-jan-16)

Mod: Not sure how this one works, but I used the same Match inside.

Index: The range that the dates are in is the row 3 (where 04-jan-16 is written), I also wrote 3 for the row of the range I am interested in.

It doesn't seem to work, and also it looks like it will only search in the first week and not the other 52 weeks.

Comment: `E5:R5` should be `E5:ABD5` since that's the range the "x"s can actually be in.  That will allow it to look in weeks past the first one (which corresponds to `E5:R5`).  And FYI, the `MOD()` means modulus and basically means remainder when the first number is divided by the second number.  It's used to find the offset within the week so the formula know how many columns to back up in order to find the date for the week.  This is necessary because, since the cells are merged, cell `F3` doesn't have a value but `E3` does so if the "x" is in column `F`, back up to `E` to get the date from row 3.

Comment: @L.Perreault Updated the formula to reflect the comments.

Comment: @Jacquez Thank you again for your dedication. In Match, when I try and write ''x'' or ''zzz'' with 0 or 1 (tried all cases), it does return me a value, but it's always 00-Jan-00 (0 in number format), no matter in what week I write it.

Comment: @L.Perreault Ah, there were more errors introduced than I counted on when translating from my test sheet to yours.  I will post a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: @L.Perreault OK, The biggest problem was `INDEX($1:$1...` which was looking on the the first row of the sheet instead of the row where the dates are.  I was also able to simplify the logic because the range for the dates exactly matches where the dates are instead of the entire row.  Finally, I also added a few static references to improve the likelihood of a successful translation.

Comment: @Jacquez  Sir, you are a real savior! It works! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @L.Perreault Very glad I could help!  Please select this as the answer so that everyone will benefit, seeing that this is the solution to the problem.